# LPCSTR creates undeclared variable in CLR project

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a c++ function in a dll wrapper that takes a char *, converts it to LPCSTR then uses it as a variable in a MessageBox. The function and the conversion work fine in the original class, but when I try to use the function in a CLR project I get an Undeclared Identifier error with the LPCSTR variable.

Empty project class header:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class StringPass {
public:

    void stringPass(char *inbound);

};
```

Empty project class .cpp file:

```
#pragma once

#include "NewPrototypes.h"

#include <Windows.h>

void StringPass::stringPass(char *inbound)
{
    LPCSTR inBound = inbound;

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT(inBound), TEXT("Succesful Test"), MB_OK);
}
```

When I run this as a stand alone project it works perfectly.

CLR project header:

```
#pragma once

#include "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewProtoClass\NewProtoClass\NewPrototypes.h"
#include "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewProtoClass\NewProtoClass\NewPrototypes.cpp"

using namespace System;

namespace NewPrototypesDll {

    public ref class StringPassWrapper
    {
    public:
        StringPassWrapper();

        void stringPassWrapper(char *inbound);
    private:
        StringPass *stringPassClass;
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

CLR project .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "NewPrototypesDll.h"

#include "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewProtoClass\NewProtoClass\NewPrototypes.h"
#include "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewProtoClass\NewProtoClass\NewPrototypes.cpp"

NewPrototypesDll::StringPassWrapper::StringPassWrapper()
{
    stringPassClass = new StringPass();
}

void NewPrototypesDll::StringPassWrapper::stringPassWrapper(char *inbound)
{
    stringPassClass->stringPass(inbound);
}
```

When I try to build the DLL file, I get the error:

```
1>C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewProtoClass\NewProtoClass\NewPrototypes.cpp(11): error C2065: 'LinBound' : undeclared identifier
```

I've tried everything, I've added windows.h to the project but this error keeps popping up. Yes I've looked at the other questions regarding undeclared identifier errors but none were unique to my situation, and none of the solutions worked. Why does it work in the first portion of the project, but not the other?

Comment: try replacing '\' with '\\' like `"C:\\Users\Ryan\\...`.

Comment: No that doesn't work, I would have gotten a different error if it was a syntax issue with the path name.

Comment: can you show us your NewPrototypes.cpp?

Comment: I did, second code block down. or are you asking for the "main()" file?

Comment: search for `LinBound` and change it to `inBound`. seems like you have written `LinBound` by mistake.

Comment: No, like peter said below, TEXT in the message box call adds L to the front of the argument in unicode mode, and a CLR project is in unicode mode. That's why it worked as a simple console project, but not when I was trying to make a DLL. I wrote 'inBound' but L is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEXT() is for literals, not variables. Notice that the error message says "LinBound" -- TEXT adds an L to the front of its argument in Unicode mode, and CLR is in Unicode mode. Either call MessageBoxA directly, or use MultiByteToWideChar to convert to Unicode.

Comment: MessageBoxA yielded the same error, but I got the answer I needed. An incompatibility with the code. I'll search for a way around it, or another way to complete my project. Thank you.

Comment: Did you also remove TEXT() around the variable name? That is the source of the compiler error.

Comment: you mean just put the variable? yeah i tried that, i got this error:  C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\NewProtoClass\\NewProtoClass\\NewPrototypes.cpp(11): error C2664: 'MessageBox' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'LPCSTR' to 'LPCTSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Figured it out, I had to use the variable on both TEXT arguments with message box A, thanks for all your help. it built the DLL.